# How can I return a value that uses a trait as a type/interface?

Tags: rust, traits

Specifically, I'd like to use either `io::stdin()` or `File::open()` as `io::Read`.

I am new to Rust and may be missing some concepts, but I am unable to find any documentation as to how to return a struct containing a trait.

Example of that I am trying to achieve:

```
use std::io::{self, Error};
use std::fs::File;

struct Config<T: io::Read> {
    source: T,
    dest: T,
}

impl<T> Config<T>
where
    T: io::Read,
{
    fn new(args: &[String]) -> Result<Config, Box<Error>> {
        if args.len() == 1 {
            Ok(Config {
                source: io::stdin(),
                dest: io::stdout(),
            })
        } else if args.len() == 2 {
            Ok(Config {
                source: File::open(args[1])?,
                dest: io::stdout(),
            })
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut config = Config::new(&[""]);
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
  --> src/main.rs:13:39
   |
13 |     fn new(args: &[String]) -> Result<Config, Box<Error>> {
   |                                       ^^^^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the error message complains about the missing type parameter to `Config`.  Just use `Config<T>` instead.

Comment: The linked duplicates [applied to your specific problem](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=3c1e785b89c464f9e78efe379d21834a&version=stable). As explained in the first duplicate, you cannot accept a generic `T` and then decide what `T` should be in the function. As explained in the second duplicate, you need a *trait object* to perform dynamic dispatch. Then there's just a lot of little bugs like the fact that `stdout` doesn't implement `io::Read`, missing if clauses, and mismatched types.

Comment: @SvenMarnach no, that will not work. Please read the first linked duplicate to understand why.

Comment: @Shepmaster I did not mean to imply that everything works with that fixed.  I just meant to explain the specific error message, which is unrelated to the other issues.  I see that my wording is misleading.